# how to see values of a map in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have wrapper classes for all STL containers. And I want to see values contained in one of the map while debugging my code base on gdb. I already have .gdbinit with all stl-views. And currently my gdb is recognizing all stl commands like pmap, pvector etc. but when I provide my wrapper map (or any other container) object as an argument to stl commands I am getting following error.

```
(gdb) pmap wrapperMapObj
Invalid type combination in equality test.
```

How can I see values in wrapper objects?

Answer (score 1):

> I already have .gdbinit with all stl-views

STL-views are so last century. If you are using GDB-7.x, the new [python pretty printers](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=524) will likely provide *much* better user experience.

> but when I provide my wrapper map

Since you haven't explained what your "wrapper map" is, how could we possibly answer your question about it?

Comment: my wrapper map is a of type std::map<string,boost_shared_ptr>